# How to fix longtable and bigfoot LaTeX packages conflict?

Tags: longtable, bigfoot

When I compile a single *.tex file on my local machine, it seems like the `longtable` and `bigfoot` packages conflict resulting in wrong "sticking" of the table header on the next page. Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | c | c | }
\hline
\textbf{First column}  & \textbf{Second column}     \\ \hline
\endhead
test & test \\ \hline
...
test & test \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

First page is correct, while some subsequent pages are wrong: they have the header row detached from the table.

The weird thing is when I comment `\usepackage{bigfoot}` row, it works.

From my investigation:

- it works on other machines with both pdflatex and latex;
- it fails on my computer with both pdflatex and latex.

I have most of `texlive-*` packages installed in Ubuntu, and I have found that `bigfoot` loads the following during compilation:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/bigfoot.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/manyfoot.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/nccfoots.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/perpage.sty
```

I need to use `bigfoot` package, as it's used in the project I'm working with, but I want to fix the bug with `longtable`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please fix the example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @yo' the example as posted is a one page three row table, it clearly doesn't demonstrate the problem which is described as occurring after a page break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and added several identical rows in order to make the `longtable` split across pages.

The output I get at the start of the second page when I run `pdflatex` from TeX Live versions 2015 and 2014 is

[image]

If I run `pdflatex` from TeX Live version 2013, I get

[image]

In TeX Live 2014 (and 2015) I have

```
Package: bigfoot 2014/10/23 2.0 makes footnotes work
```

whereas in TeX Live 2013 I have

```
Package: bigfoot 2006/07/15 1.25 makes footnotes work
```

So the problem is having an outdated version of `bigfoot` on one of the machines. Typically Ubuntu lags behind, but newer versions of it should already sport TeX Live 2014 or even 2015.

Comment: Thanks, egreg. I certainly do have `Package: bigfoot 2006/07/15 1.25 makes footnotes work` in log. This is basically a part of the latest `texlive-latex-extra` package (2014.20141024) for Ubuntu 15.04 which I just didn't expect to be outdated! :) I will try to recompile only the `bigfoot` package myself, because upgrading `texlive-latex-extra` package to the version from Ubuntu 15.10 would pull way too many unstable dependencies. If that works, I would accept this as an answer!

Comment: @khvMX There should be no problem in pulling `bigfoot.dtx` and `bigfoot.ins` from CTAN, running `tex bigfoot.ins` and moving the generated `bigfoot.sty` into the directory `/usr/local/share/texlive/tex/latex/bigfoot`. Do `sudo -p /usr/local/share/texlive/tex/latex/bigfoot`, `sudo mv bigfoot.sty /usr/local/share/texlive/tex/latex/bigfoot` and `sudo mktexlsr`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Substituting the bigfoot.sty sufficed to fix the problem. Now it shows: `bigfoot.sty 2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work`